# Exception while runnig a javafx application jar file

Tags: exception, javafx, jar

I have a problem here with my javafx application jar, generated by Eclipse mars. Actually everything is running pretty well if I am running inside eclipse. However when I use the command line and try to run the jar of my application which was previously created by eclipse, using the command:

```
java -jar TalanTestingWithXPathFX.jar
```

I got a lot of errors in my terminal. The error are the following:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
    at talan.test.webApp.MainApp.initRootLayout(Unknown Source)
    at talan.test.webApp.MainApp.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162       (Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application talan.test.webApp.MainApp
```

Comment: Can you please add a little more code? It seems that you try to load a fxml  file, but the location (where to load from) is not set.

Comment: It has to do with the location.Maybe in Eclipse you load the files ok but when you export the jar file it is different.For example if your fxml is in different resource folder you have to use getClass().getResource(.....).Provide a picture of your eclipse project so we can see whats going on .... and the line-lines that is/are problematic.

Answer (score 0):

This is some code from the main class

```
public class MainApp extends Application {
@FXML
private static Stage primaryStage;
@FXML
private AnchorPane rootLayout;
public Project mainProject;
public static rootLayOutController rootController;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setResizable(true);
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("AutoGenDriver");
    initRootLayout();
    //showSubWindow();
}


/**
 * Initializes the root layout.
 */
public void initRootLayout() {
    try {
        // Load root layout from fxml file.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("./view/rootLayOut.fxml"));
        rootLayout = loader.load();
        // Show the scene containing the root layout.
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootLayout);

        //
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        rootController=loader.getController();
     // Give the controller access to the main app.
        rootLayOutController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);

        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Loading error");
    }
}

public void setProject(Project p){
    this.mainProject = p;
}

/**
 * Called when the user clicks New Project.
 */
@FXML
public static Project showNewProjectDialog() {
    try {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
              loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/newProjectDialog.fxml"));
    AnchorPane page = loader.load();
    // Create the dialog Stage.
    Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
    dialogStage.setTitle("Add new Test Project");
    dialogStage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    dialogStage.initOwner(primaryStage);
    Scene scene = new Scene(page);
    dialogStage.setScene(scene);
    // Set the project into the controller.
    newProjectDialogController controller = loader.getController();
    controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
   // controller.setProject(project);

    // Show the dialog and wait until the user closes it
    dialogStage.showAndWait();
    return controller.getProject();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println("Loading error");
       return null;
    }
}
  public static void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
    MainApp.primaryStage = primaryStage;
}
 /**
 * Returns the main stage.
 * @return
 */
public static Stage getPrimaryStage() {
    return primaryStage;
}
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

this is some code from the rootLayOutController class

```
public void setRootTreeView(String nameProject) {
Image image=new Image(new File("C:\\Users\\DELL 3521\\workspaceMars\\TalanTestingFX\\Images\\dossier.png").toURI().toString(),20,20,true,true);
    ImageView imv= new ImageView();
    imv.setImage(image);
    TreeItem<String> rootNode = new TreeItem<String>(tempProject.getName(),imv);
    rootNode.setExpanded(true);
    testProject.add(rootNode);
    t.setRoot(rootNode);

}


/**
 * add sub Elements to the TreeView
 *
 * @param mainApp
 */
public void addItemToTreeView(String item) {
    testProject.get(0).getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(item));
}


public static Template getTemplate() {
    return template;
}

public static void setTemplate(Template template) {
    rootLayOutController.template = template;
}

public AnchorPane getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(AnchorPane content) {
    this.content = content;
}




/**
 * Initializes the controller class. This method is automatically called
 * after the fxml file has been loaded.
 */
@FXML
private void initialize() {
    handleTreeViewSelectElement();
    newSuiteItem.setDisable(true);
    openPageItem.setDisable(true);
    cnxItem.setDisable(true);
    openPageItem.setDisable(true);
    scItem.setDisable(true);
    acItem.setDisable(true);
    dactItem.setDisable(true);

}
```